# want to query an array from parse that might be empty sometimes but xcode won't let me

Tags: xcode, swift, parse-platform, forced-unwrapping

```
func reloadFriendList() {
    var query = PFQuery(className:"userFriendClass")
    query.whereKey("username", equalTo:user!.username!)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

            for object in objects! {
                self.friendList = object["friends"] as! [String]
                print(self.friendList)
                self.reloadTableView()
            }
        } else {

            // Log details of the failure
            print("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo)")
        }

    }
}
```

i want to save object["friends"] that is an array from parse with usernames into

```
var friendList = [String]()
```

but i get the error: "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value",
when the array is empty which means the user doesn't have any friends yet it works fine when the user have at least 1 or more friends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have your code ready to handle nil cases and cases where "`objects`" is an empty array.

If this were my code, I would do something like:

```
for object in objects {
    if let friendList = object["friends"]
    {
         self.friendList = friendList
    } else {
         // make sure that your class's `friendList` var is declared as an optional
         self.friendList = [String]()
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh i forgot to delete old line it shouldn't be there i was just trying another way to solve it i edited the post!

Answer (score 1):

Since `objects` is optional and may be `nil`, you need to unwrap it safely. One way to do that is to use the *nil coalescing operator* to unwrap it or to substitute an empty array if `objects` is `nil`.  You can use it again to safely unwrap the list of friends:

```
for object in objects ?? [] {
    self.friendList = (object["friends"] as? [String]) ?? []
```

You can also use *optional binding* `if let` to safely unwrap things:

```
if let unwrappedObjects = objects {
    for object in unwrappedObjects {
        if let friends = object["friends"] as? [String] {
            self.friendsList = friends
        } else {
            // no friends :-(
            self.friendsList = []
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: nice! I didn't notice the declaration that objects could be optional.

Comment: objects is not actually never nil it is always 1 its the object["friends"] that sometimes is nil, however i tried your solution it didn't work

Comment: you can use the *nil coalescing operator* again to safely unwrap the array of friends.  See updated answer.